# Finding Index at which the Measure First equals or Exceeds 70% of Max and Falls Below 70% of Max

Tags: r

To start, I have a data table (`RRLong`) containing subject ID numbers (n = 15), the type of trial that subjects were exposed to (10 trial types, within-subject factor), and the block of test sessions (5 blocks, within-subject factor). On each trial, for each block, there were 80 sequential bins for which responding was measured. The last column contains the response rate (`RR`) for a given bin.

```
ID  TrialType   Block   Bin RR
1   E.Cue       1       1   0.369047619
1   E.Cue       1       2   0.447916667
1   E.Cue       1       3   0.435185185
```

When `RR` is plotted as a function of `bin`, the data approximates the shape of a Gaussian distribution.

From these data, I need to calculate the following measures, for each subject on each trial type on each block (thus, 750 values based on the number of subjects, blocks, and trial  types):

1. `PR`: The maximum response rate
2. `PT`: The bin at which the maximum response rate was located
3. `Initial`: The bin at which response rate first equals or exceeds 70% of the maximum response rate.
4. `Final`: The bin at which response rate first equals or falls below 70% of the maximum response rate; this value must be later than the value of `PT`.

I have managed to extract the first two measures using the following code using `dplyr`:

```
MolarMeasures <- RRLong %>% 
   group_by(ID,TrialType,Block) %>%                            
   slice(which.max(RR)) %>%
   select(PT = Bin, PR = RR)
```

However, I am at a loss for how to calculate the last two measures. I would appreciate any insight/advice. Please let me know if any additional information is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided enough data to test things out, but this should work.

```
MolarMeasures <- RRLong %>% 
   group_by(ID,TrialType,Block) %>%                            
   summarize(
      PR = max(RR),
      PT = Bin[which.max(RR)],
      Initial = Bin[which.max(RR >= 0.7 * PR)],
      Final = which.max((RR <= 0.7 * PR) & cumsum(RR >= PR)),
      Final = ifelse(Final == 1, NA, Bin[Final])
   )
```

Explanation: `PR` and `PT` are straightforward. For the last two we take advantage that TRUE/FALSE can be treated as 1/0, and `which.max` will return the index of the *first* maximum (first TRUE). For `Final` we also use `cumsum` to make sure that the max has been met at least once. The `cumsum` result will be `0`/`FALSE` before the maximum and (not `0`)/`TRUE` afterwards.

Comment: This works perfectly! I have two additional questions, if you wouldn't mind. 1) If the response rate never drops below 70% of the maximum, the function returns a value of `1` for `Final`. I can assign these values to be recoded as an NA later on, but is there another way to do it within the `summarize` function? 2) If I'm looking to restrict my analysis to a range of bins (say 2-80, rather than 1-80), then the measures of `PT`, `initial`, and `final` are off by one, as the index values are used to determine the location. Is there a way to use `Bin` to locate these values instead?